# Why use of eval() is not recommended

Tags: javascript

I have used eval() function in my code but Sonar is suggesting me to not to use eval(). What are the consequences and is there any alternative?

Comment: this should answer your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval! as well as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: duplicate of [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Use of `eval()` depends on what _you_ are trying to achieve.